# Why python need global keyword while C/C++ no need?

Tags: python, c++, global-variables, global

If I want change a global variable, I could do it directly in C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 1;

int main()
{
    x = 1 + x;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

But got error using Python:

```
x = 1
def foo():
    x += 1

foo()
```

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

I have to add `global x` in function `foo` to make it.

---

Seems python make it more explicit, is "just to be explicit" the reason?

Comment: C++ and Python are two different languages, with different rules, different syntax, etc.

Comment: I always fail to understand why beginners expect *entirely different* languages to behave similarly. There's a *reason* why they are different languages; they do things *differently*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yeah different languages should have at least one difference. But I think know why they have that difference will be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental difference is that C and C++ have variable declarations. The location of the declaration determines whether a global is declared.

In Python, you only have assignments. An assignment to a yet-unassigned variable creates that variable. An assignment to an existing variable changes that variable. Hence, without `global` you couldn't create a local variable if a global variable with that name existed.

Comment: but `+=` doesn't look like an assignment. It would be worth explaining that if python sees a variable on the LHS of an expression, it's seen as local (even if it's `+=` which looks "in place"). And even if `x` doesn't exist as global `x += 1` fails as x doesn't exist

Comment: @MSalters _"Hence, without global you couldn't create a local variable if a global variable with that name existed."_ This is actually wrong. If he was written `x = 2`, a local `x` would have been created, even if the global one already exists with the same name, and these would be two different variables.

Comment: @Fareanor: That's true under the current rules, but my answer covers the hypothetical case where there's no `global`.

Answer (score 2):

without the `global` keyword, `x` doesn't exist in the function. When the parser sees

```
x += 1
```

it assumes that `x` is a local variable (because it's on the left hand side of the expression)

Now when `+=` tries to change the value of the variable, since `x` doesn't exist as a local variable, it fails.

Note that it cannot be workarounded without the `global` keyword for immutable types, but for mutable types like `list` you could make without it.

This fails the same way as with integer, because the parser doesn't care about types:

```
x = []
def foo():
    x += [12]
```

but this works, as `x` isn't seen as a local by the parser.

```
x = []
def foo():
    x.extend([12])
```

At any rate, avoiding global variables avoids a lot of head-scratching. You can use other patterns most of the time (like singleton objects).

```
class MyTool:
   def __init__(self):
      self.x = 12
   def add_one_to_x(self):
      self.x += 1

m = MyTool()
m.add_one_to_x()
```

`x` is an instance variable, shared between all methods of your singleton object. See? no need for globals now (well, except for `m` but 1) there's only one global variable in the project and 2) it can also be defined in a main function)

Answer (score 0):

I think @MSalters 's answer solved my question very well. But I want to talk more about `x = 1 + x` in Python and C/C++.

---

TL;DR

In both C/C++ and Python, if there is a global variable `x` and a statement `(int) x = 1 + x` in a function. Python will report a error like I posted in the question, C/C++ should be UNDEFINED. In fact, the reason as it is UNDEFINED in C/C++ is same with Python: use local variable `x` before assignment.

---

Detail about why it is WRONG(UNDEFINED) in C/C++, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 1;

int main()
{
    int x = 1 + x;  // Here compiler know we take not only first x as a local variable but also the second. It means first and second x point to same memory.
    printf("%d\n", x);  // print 1.
    return 0;
}
```

as `clang` complains: `[clangtidy] The right operand of '+' is a garbage value [clang-analyzer-core.UndefinedBinaryOperatorResult] [W]`.

Corresponding assemble code is:

```
x:
    .long   1
    .section    .rodata
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)  // 1 + local x, if use global x it should be: movl    x(%rip), %eax THEN: addl    $1, %eax
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  // use result of 1 + local x as print's arg
    movl    %eax, %esi
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

It shows we never use the global `x`. And why compiler not use global `x`, maybe not deserve it as it's a wrong/confused writing style.

---

So in C/C++ compiler knows all the code below refer to a new variable in this scope when compiler see a `variable declaration`，like `int x = 1 + x;`. It is a global variable if no `variable declaration`, like `x = 1 + x` in a function.

But in python the interpreter was confused when `x += 1` or `x = 1 + x` was read, as @MSalters 's answer said python no `variable declaration`. Python adopt assignments refer the variable in current scope to make it more specific, otherwise interpreter should track call chain to find the variable(or just find it at global scope), then it will be bad when you want declare a variable as `x` in current scope.